# REST API: Combine login information and API action using C#?

Tags: c#, api, rest, restful-authentication

I am trying to use name.com API in C#. The API has different actions including /Login, /account/get, /create/domain and more. You can find the documentation [here](http://www.name.com/reseller/api-documentation)

The /Login method is POST and the body is a JSON, and done it with HttpWebRequest and it works successfully. It returns something like:

```
    {
        "result": {
                    "code":100,
                    "message":"Command Successful"
                  },
        "session_token":"a59a09be6562e977a166fdd2b345a235c8b6c724"
    }
```

But after login, I need to use the other services (run the other API actions).

Here I am sending another HttpWebRequest as:

```
    string base = "https://api.dev.name.com/api/"
    HttpWebRequest request;
    request = WebRequest.Create(base + "account/get") as HttpWebRequest;  
    ....
    ....
```

Instead of returning the account information, it returns an error which says:

```
    {
      "result": 
      {
        "code":251,
        "message":"Authentication Error - No Api Session Or Username Token Supplied"
      }
    }
```

I think that I need a way to send the request along with the login information. The err message here is "Authentication Error - No Api Session Or Username Token Supplied"

**NOTE: There is PHP sample code and classes for this API. Here is the link of the [API Documentation](http://www.name.com/reseller/api-documentation)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See page 18 of the [documentation](http://www.name.com/files/name_api_documentation.pdf).  You need to pass the returned session token as a request header:

```
Api-Session-Token: <session_token>
```

So, once you get the response and get the token, you would just add the following line:

```
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Api-Session-Token", <session_token>);
```